# How do I import an alternative pom.xml file in m2eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

The only possible input is a directory where m2eclipse will automatically scan for pom.xml. What if you want to import an alternative file (say abc.xml)? can it be done and how?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. m2e relies on the presence of a pom.xml. The only way to have a different behaviour in m2e is to use maven profiles. The following will be activated automatically when using m2e :

```
<profile>
  <id>m2e</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>m2e.version</name>
    </property>
  </activation>
 ...
</profile>
```

Your CLI builds will remain unaffected, unless you manually use the m2e profile.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is pretty dependent on the pom.xml keeping it's name; repos, developers and other tools expect it to be there for a maven project.

Comment: I don't disagree but mvn supports -f parameter (-f,--file Force the use of an alternate POM file.). Is there a similar option for m2eclipse?

Comment: That is a new flag for me. Could be useful for scripting on top of maven. I did an egrep in one of my workspaces for pom.xml and the only thing that matched was jar files. Looks like it is either a really well hidden setting or not possible. Maybe a symlink to your real pom will work?

Comment: Maven can definitely support alternate pom file names. You are right though that in practice tools will make the assumption of the name of the manifest being pom.xml. Note though that in the repository, even if a project uses a custom pom file name, the installed artifact will have pom.xml as the file name.

Answer (score 0):

in the eclipse navigator view, right click on your project and click new->file
click advanced and check off "link to a file in the file system" and specify the path