# Importing a Maven project with custom pom name in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

How do I import in Eclipse a Maven project (I have the m2e plugin) using a non-default pom2.xml like this:

```
project
   + src
   + pom2.xml
   + pom.xml
```

I can build the project with `mvn clean install -f pom2.xml`, but I can't import in Eclipse. It seems m2e is missing this feature.

EDIT: duplicate of: [How do I import an alternative pom.xml file in m2eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640143/how-do-i-import-an-alternative-pom-xml-file-in-m2eclipse)

Comment: Just curious, any particular reason not to have it as pom.xml?

Comment: did you try: mvn eclipse:eclipse ?

Comment: You can create a pom.xml that refer to pom2.xml ?

Comment: I want to work in a new pom without touching the default one. I'll have to do many commits before ending my work and I can't modify the original pom until it's done. I'd like to avoid branching, although I know it's an option. Bottom line, maven has this -f feature, but m2e seems not to have it although it could be very helpful

Comment: Can't you just rename the old to pom2.xml and change the original?

Comment: I don't see how this would help, what I want is to import a Maven project using the pom2.xml instead of the default.

Comment: @user503413 mvn eclipse:eclipse -f pom2.xml may work, but it's terrible to work with it because whenever I change the pom I'd have to re-run this command so Eclipse can understand the new dependencies I added

Comment: if you use m2eclipse and refresh the project using the maven tools?

Comment: @user503413 I can't even import the project in the first place. Anyway, I tried importing with pom.xml and renaming to pom2.xml after. The project gets broken

Comment: you can try, but I haven't so I cannot guarantee it will work, to create the project with `mvn eclipse:eclipse -f pom2.xml`, then import it into eclipse. From the IDE, do `Maven` -> `Disable Maven nature`, then do a `Run as` -> `Maven build..` and in that Window, write `eclipse:clean` as goal. Finally, re-enable the maven nature for the project. Actually, as you also noted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640143/how-do-i-import-an-alternative-pom-xml-file-in-m2eclipse m2e relies on `pom.xml`, so the solution I gave you may not work.

Comment: @mardavi I was suggested something similar in one of the previous comments. The problem is that I need to use m2e, otherwise pom modifications won't reflect immediately in the project, I'd have to run eclipse:eclipse for every change

Comment: I read previous comments. My point is: once the project is in eclipse, if you "disconnect" (basically, `mvn eclipse:clean` will delete .project and other eclipse-related files), disconnect it from Maven but you keep it in the IDE window, then reconnecting it to Maven may work. There are few steps didn't suggest earlier. But probably it won't work, I keep thinking to the sentence "m2e needs pom.xml".

Comment: FYI, per [Jason Van Zyl](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg02775.html), "The use of the maven-eclipse-plugin (eclipse:eclipse, eclipse:clean) is not supported with m2eclipse. You either use m2eclipse on its own or use, or use the maven-eclipse-plugin on its own."  I've seen various forum postings discussing problems when trying to use both together.  Caveat Programmor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible.

More information can be found at: [How do I import an alternative pom.xml file in m2eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640143/how-do-i-import-an-alternative-pom-xml-file-in-m2eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

I tried and succeed in importing a maven project with pom2.xml as its pom in the following way:

> mvn clean install -f pom2.xml

from the command line.

Import existing projects from eclipse.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: it doesn't work correctly. The project is added to Eclipse, but it is not considered a Maven project. Trying to add some dependencies in the pom2.xml won't have any effect

Comment: I added also some dependencies to the pom. Took the same approach, it was successful with import, dependencies and all. But, you are right: it wasn't considered a maven project.

Comment: you may have to run mvn eclipse:eclipse command to generate eclipse project configuration files